# Put console on ttyS0 if guest OS is booted headlessly

Tags: debian, shell-script, virtualbox, init

We're using Debian 4 (No systemd) for our product. I run it as a guest OS managed by VirtualBox for testing purposes.

#### Here's how I use it:

- For manual debugging, I have the guest OS's console on its tty1 and I fire up a range of debug programs on it.
- For testing with scripts, I move the console to ttyS0 (The hosts python hooks into it so easily). I don't run the debugging programs for performance.

#### What I have so far:

I can detect if the virtual machine serial port is enabled or not. I grep for ttyS0 in dmesg. (I've been told to look at /proc instead but I'd rather not have to enable/disable the serial port at all)

#### What I think the main question is:

Is there a way for a shell script on a Debain OS to tell if it's being run headlessly by VirtualBox? I have bash available.

#### Update 1:

I'm starting to suspect the answer is no.
Executing lspci shows that the VGA compatible controller is the VirtualBox Graphics Adapter in both headless and normal mode. I've read remote viewing of a headless guest is possible by default if the host is configured to serve it. This points to no detectable change from the guests perspective.

Comment: Debian 4 hasn't been supported since 2010, are you sure that's the version you're using?

Comment: @Wieland Yeah, but it is a legacy product.

Comment: On QEMU that's probably would be much more easier since QEMU can load kernels directly and apply custom cmdlines to them, so you would end up with just two shell scripts to run Debian in different modes. Consider switching to QEMU if there are no VBox-specific features in use.

Answer (score 0):

Use shell scripts on the host to modify and start the vms:

normal_boot

```
#!/bin/bash
vboxmanage modifyvm "Vir153_1000" --uart1 off
vboxmanage startvm "Vir153_1000"
```

headless_boot

```
#!/bin/bash
vboxmanage modifyvm "Vir153_1000" --uart1 0x3F8 4
vboxheadless --startvm "Vir153_1000" --vrde off &
```

The guest is still required to check for the presence of a serial port and act accordingly.

Thanks @siblynx for the idea